# Configure Crystal Reports 11 to Run Report When Condition Is Met?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement to generate a report for a client, but only when a certain condition is met.  In this case, it's when employees hit their 15 or 20 year mark of service.  Obviously, this isn't something that occurs every day and so the HR staff would like this report only sent to them when this does occur and not receive a blank report every day.

Any idea how to configure a report to only run or only get delivered when the data meets a certain criterion?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking your criteria before you even get to the crystal report file.  Personally, I would make an Access database that:

1. gets the data
2. checks your criteria
3. If criteria is met, run & email the report (either with a shell command or via the Crystal APIs).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data coming from?

What is actually RUNNING the Crystal Report?  If it's a person, then they get a calendar and copy of the personnel hire dates (grin).

If it's BOXI Enterprise, then there are event-triggers that can be set and reports run from the event.  Alternately, BOXI allows you to suppress empty reports.

Alternately, if this is a scheduled report, if you can make the schedule fail on an internal condition, that would work as well.  (Report "XYearAnniversary" is scheduled to run once a month.  The report prints a list of employees based on their anniverary for years of service in (5,10,15,20,25,30) for that month.  If no employees meet the two criteria, the report is empty.  Either the scheduler is set to suppress empty reports, or the resulting report is a single page to that effect. etc.)